# jq - how can I flat my list of lists into one level list

Tags: json, jq, flatten

how can I have transformed my json

```
{
    "clients": [
    {
     "id" : "qwerty",
     "accounts" : [{"number" : "6666"}, {"number" : "7777"}]
    },
    {
     "id" : "zxcvb",
     "accounts" : [{"number" : "1111"}, {"number" : "2222"}] 
    }
]
}
```

into following type of json? using **JQ**

```
{
"items": [
{
"id" : "qwerty",
"number" : "6666"
},{
"id" : "qwerty",
"number" : "7777"
},{
"id" : "zxcvb",
"number" : "1111"
},{
"id" : "zxcvb",
"number" : "2222"
}]
}
```

What kind of tools from JQ can help me? I can't choose any possible way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
{items: [.clients[] | {id} + .accounts[]]}
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/h-S9bcY2ks)</sup>